# Tomcat URL Rewrite with multiple domains and SSL

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting

I have a problem with my tomcat 7 configuration; I was previously using the tuckey URL Rewrite library to redirect non www and non https traffic to the https+www URL using this config:

```
<rule>
  <name>Canonical Hostnames</name>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.mydomain.net</condition>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://www.mydomain.net/$1</to>
</rule>
```

I have just purchased the .com version of my domain; and have successfully setup the SSL certificate for it.  I changed the config above to use the .com url instead & now I would like all .net traffic, non www, and non https all to redirect to the https+www+.com url.  Currently when I visit the .net version of my website it doesn't redirect to the .com & I see an ssl certificate error in my browser as obviously the site is setup to use the .com ssl cert.

Any help would be much appreciated - I'm not tied to tuckey as a solution.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know the library in question, but the xml snippet you provide looks as if you can have multiple distinct rules - e.g. one per domain. This might be easier than relying on wildcards. If this doesn't help, you might want to post your non-working configuration for the .net/.com domains so that we can see what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
<rule>
  <name>Canonical Hostnames</name>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^www.example.com</condition>
  <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
  <from>^/(.*)</from>
  <to type="permanent-redirect" last="true">https://www.example.com/$1</to>
</rule>
```

Should do you.. simply change the .net to .com. Now anything that isn't www.mydomain.com will become it.